# Can I edit codes on multiple files simultaneously in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

While making a website, I find myself editing the navbar multiple times.  Right now, I manually edit them across all my pages.  Is there a way, with or without addons, to automatically sync-up blocks of texts across all my files, similar to the multi-cursor editing.
Thank you

Comment: That's the wrong question to ask. The right question is how do I avoid having duplicated blocks in different files ?

Comment: Don't do like that. Firstly, design your website layout (rough sketch). Then, basic design(i.e. design that will be on all pages) should be made only in one page, then copy it in other html files. During, backend you will using templates, where you will be able to extend from main html file all over which will exactly do what you want.  What I am saying is just suggestion!!!

Comment: You can use Adobe Dreamweaver. Create a temple for these files, when you modify the template all derived files will update. But better to use Biplove method of using a template engine